# How can I run a Java file from a shell script and keep that shell script running?

Tags: java, bash, debian

I have a control variable which I watch in a Bash script. If that variable is a certain value, I want to start a Java file, but keep watching that variable for a change. If it changes, I’d like to kill the Java process.

I know how to kill the process, but I am unsure as to how I can run these two in parallel.

When I try my implementation, the bash script pauses for the Java code.

I am using Debian for this task.

Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Two scripts.  One to start the Java, another one to monitor.  The monitor can use the output of `ps` with a `grep` to filter out the process you want, and the variable.  Then call the start script to restart it.  This way the start script completes, and the monitoring done in the other script keeps going on.   You may be able to use systemd for that.  I know it can monitor process and restart it, I do not know if it can monitor a variable though.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, I think you just need to start the Java program in the background (leaving the  Bash code able to continue), continue monitoring the variable, and kill the background process when it changes.  You should be able to find everything that you need in [ProcessManagement - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Comment: Is there a reason that you aren't running the java process in the background, as @pjh suggests?

Comment: @pjh thanks for the resource! I was able to complete my objective with a few modifications to how I was doing things and the resources found within that link. Thanks again!